# What does it mean "All Scripture is God-breathed"?

Tags: 2-peter, 2-timothy

2 Timothy 3:16

> All Scripture is God-breathed and is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness.

To me the sentence is difficult to find the chronological order, because what I thought is something like this :

There is a writing. 
Someone read that writing then try to conclude/decide whether it is useful for teaching/rebuking/correcting and training in righteousness or not.

If he/she doesn't find the writings is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness, then he/she say *"it's not inspired by God"*, hence the writing cannot be called a Scripture.

If he/she finds the writing is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness, then he/she says *"it's inspired by God"*, hence the writing cab be called a Scripture.

But it seems my chronological order above is not correct. I've read some sentences in this [link](https://www.monergism.com/reformed-doctrine-inspiration) like these :

> Peter includes Paul’s epistles with the “other scriptures”

and this [link](https://www.monergism.com/revelation-scripture-word-god)

> Already Peter refers to Paul’s letters as Scripture

2 Peter 3:15

> Bear in mind that our Lord's patience means salvation, just as our dear brother **Paul also wrote you with the wisdom that God gave him**.

This leads me to a different conclusion:
The first thing is that Paul in the point of view of Peter is a man with God's wisdom. So then every Paul's writing to any church is Scripture, useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness.

In other words, Peter doesn't need to read any of Paul's letter to the church in order to decide/conclude whether Paul's letter is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness or not because God Himself told Peter that Paul is a man with His wisdom.

So, I'm in two options :
A. It's called Scripture (God breathed) because after reading the writing - the reader conclude that the writing is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness

B. It's Scripture (God breathed) because the writing is written by a man with God's wisdom.

Which one is the correct one ?
I hope there is an option C which is the answer.

---

Illustration:
Suppose there is  Mr.Y being handed a letter by Mr.X ... and Mr.X said *"this letter is Scripture (God breathed)"*. Mr.Y ask *"why?"*

Point-B is something like this : 
Mr. X answer *"because the writer is a holy man, he has God's wisdom"*. 
Both Mr.X and Mr.Y doesn't know at all what are the sentences inside the letter (they don't need to read it), since the letter itself is Scripture (God breathed) because it's written by a holy man.

Point-A is something like this :
Mr. X answer *"because I've read it, and I conclude that the letter is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness."*
Here, to Mr.X the letter is Scripture (God breathed) after Mr. A read it, but not to Mr.B (yet).

Mr. Y reply *"really ? let me read it first"*.
Only after Mr.B read the letter and if he get the same conclusion with Mr.A, then the letter is also Scripture (God breathed) to Mr. B. But if after reading it Mr.B doesn't have the same conclusion with Mr.A, then the letter is not Scripture (God breathed) to Mr. A

Answer (score 2):

Peace.

Holy men of God spoke prophecy of the Scripture as they were moved by the Holy Spirit and so the interpretation of the Scriptures must also be through the Holy Spirit (which makes them “God breathed”) even now.   This God-breathed preaching of the Scriptures has power within those who will hear and believe.

Prophecy of Scripture without the understanding/movement of the Holy Spirit behind it =  the “private interpretation” of Scripture.

> 2 Peter 1:20-21 KJV (20)  *Knowing this first, that no prophecy of the
>   scripture is of any private interpretation. (21)  For the prophecy
>   came not in old time by the will of man: **but holy men of God spake as
>   they were moved by the Holy Ghost**.*

Peter said that the “unlearned and unstable” wrest or twist Paul’s letters as well as the other Scriptures unto their own destruction.   One can only understand the Scriptures through the Spirit of God which makes them “living”.

> 2 Peter 3:16 KJV (16)  *As also in all his epistles, speaking in them
>   of these things; in which are some things hard to be understood, **which
>   they that are unlearned and unstable wrest, as they do also the other
>   scriptures, unto their own destruction***.

The good news that Paul preached  in his epistles was not received by man neither was he taught it but he received it by the revelation of Jesus Christ.  The things Paul speaks about in his letters were directly revealed to him by Jesus Christ which makes them scripture.

> Galatians 1:11-12 KJV (11)  ***But I certify you, brethren***, **that the
>   gospel which was preached of me is not after man. (12)  For I neither
>   received it of man, neither was I taught it, but by the revelation of
>   Jesus Christ**.

The Scriptures were written by men of God who were moved by the Spirit.  And so the Scriptures must also be “God breathed”….preached through the Holy Spirit… so that they are properly understood.

Without being God breathed, the private interpretation of the scriptures then becomes the “word of men”.

The Word of God spoken in truth….spoken in the Spirit of Truth….effectually works in those who will hear and believe.

This is a difference between one who preaches in the Spirit of Truth and one that does not (a  man preaching through his own private interpretation):   the preaching of the Word of God in truth has power as it works in the hearts of those who will believe.   There is a demonstration of the Spirit within the heart when we hear the interpretation of the Scriptures through the Spirit of God (being God breathed).    The Spirit of God makes them “living”.  Jesus speaks words of life and spirit.   The Spirit of God brings the Scriptures to life and imparts life to those who will hear and believe.

> 1 Thessalonians 2:13 KJV (13)  ***For this cause also thank we God
>   without ceasing, because, when ye received the word of God which ye
>   heard of us, ye received it not as the word of men, but as it is in
>   truth, the word of God, which effectually worketh also in you that
>   believe.***

The Word of God interpreted via the Spirit of God has power. The light shines within the heart as men  of God speak as they are moved by the Holy Spirit.

> 2 Peter 1:19-21 KJV (19)  ***We have also a more sure word of prophecy;
>   whereunto ye do well that ye take heed, as unto a light that shineth
>   in a dark place, until the day dawn, and the day star arise in your
>   hearts: (20)  Knowing this first, that no prophecy of the scripture is
>   of any private interpretation***. (21)  For the prophecy came not in old
>   time by the will of man: but holy men of God spake as they were moved
>   by the Holy Ghost.

Only through the Spirit of God….as the Holy Spirit teaches…can we understand the Scriptures.   This is what makes them “God breathed”.

> 1 Corinthians 2:9-14 KJV (9)  *But as it is written, Eye hath not seen,
>   nor ear heard, neither have entered into the heart of man, the things
>   which God hath prepared for them that love him. (10)  But God hath
>   revealed them unto us by his Spirit: for the Spirit searcheth all
>   things, yea, the deep things of God. (11)  For what man knoweth the
>   things of a man, save the spirit of man which is in him? e**ven so the
>   things of God knoweth no man, but the Spirit of Go**d.*

Only through the Spirit which is of God can we know the things that He has freely given to us.  The words of man’s wisdom of the Scriptures teaches things which are natural and not spiritual.  the things of the Bible are spiritually discerned.

> (12)  *Now we have received, not the spirit of the world, but the
>   spirit which is of God; that we might know the things that are freely
>   given to us of God. (13)  **Which things also we speak, not in the words
>   which man's wisdom teacheth, but which the Holy Ghost teacheth;
>   comparing spiritual things with spiritual. (14)  But the natural man
>   receiveth not the things of the Spirit of God:** for they are
>   foolishness unto him: neither can he know them, **because they are
>   spiritually discerned**.*

All Scriptures ( that is God breathed) then is profitable towards (facing) doctrine, towards (facing) reproof, towards (facing) correction, and towards (facing) instruction in righteousness.

> 2 Timothy 3:16-17 KJV (16)  *All scripture is given by inspiration of
>   God, **and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for
>   instruction in righteousness:** (17)  That the man of God may be
>   perfect, throughly furnished unto all good works.*

This is what the 4 “living” creatures  of Revelation 4 are with the 4 faces….the Scriptures that are “living” (God breathed via the 7 Spirits of God) and are profitable towards or facing these things.

> Revelation 4:5-8 KJV (5)  *And out of the throne proceeded lightnings
>   and thunderings and voices: and there were seven lamps of fire burning
>   before the throne, which are the seven Spirits of God. (6)  And before
>   the throne there was a sea of glass like unto crystal: and in the
>   midst of the throne, and round about the throne, **were four beasts full
>   of eyes before and behind. (7)  And the first beast was like a lion,
>   and the second beast like a calf, and the third beast had a face as a
>   man, and the fourth beast was like a flying eagle.** (8)  And the four
>   beasts had each of them six wings about him; and they were full of
>   eyes within: and they rest not day and night, saying, Holy, holy,
>   holy, Lord God Almighty, which was, and is, and is to come.*

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer, MSW. But I'm sorry as I realize that I'm limited in my English so maybe I can't put my question clear. I've edited my question which I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @MSW What's the basis for connecting the 4 faces in Rev 4:5-8 and the 4 uses of scripture in 2 Tim 3:16-17?  Can you cite a commentary / paper discussing the connection?

Comment: Hi GratefulDisciple.  There are various scriptures being used to support the connection such as an ox/calf symbolizing teaching (1 Timothy 5:18) the Word of God. There are many “eyes”…eyewitnesses… of Jesus in the Scriptures before and behind both in the New and Old Testaments.   I don’t know if there are any commentaries making that specific connection.  The only commentaries that I have seen that are close to connecting them with the Scriptures are those who connect the 4 faces with the 4 gospels only.